# problems in setting an envirenment using yeoman

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I am trying to set up my project environment for `angular` project using `yeoman generator.` 
There is node, npm installed in my system.

I tried this command

```
npm install --global yo
```

and then followed all the instructions like what are needed but I am unable to have the folders in my project folder. 
Showing this error. 
[image]

Tried many times but showing the same error again and again.
what should I do? Please help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM throws error without sudo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)